# Rotate a cube along a line segment

Tags: geometry, rotations

Given a unit cube with one corner at $(0,0,0)$ and the opposite corner at $(1,1,1)$, derive the transformations necessary to rotate the cube by $\theta$ degrees about the line segment $[AB]$, $A(0,0,0)$ and $B(0.5,1,0.5)$ in the clockwise direction when looking along the diagonal from B to A ?

By transformations, I mean translations and rotations (only about the $x,y$ and $z$ axis).

What would be the algorithm to achieve that ?

Comment: Compute the 3×3 rotation matrix from the [axis and angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle). Then, pick the [Euler or Tait-Bryan angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) (axes and order) you want to use, and find the angles that produce the matrix that corresponds to the axis-and-angle matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X(\phi)$, $Y(\phi)$ and $Z(\phi)$ be counterclockwise rotations of angle $\phi$ about the axes. Let $\alpha=\arctan(1/2)$ be the angle formed by the projection of $[AB]$ on $xy$ plane with $y$ axis, and $\beta=\arctan(\sqrt5)$ the angle formed by $[AB]$ with $z$ axis.

Notice that $Z(\alpha)$ carries $[AB]$ to $[AB']$ on $zy$ plane, and $X(\beta)$ carries $[AB']$ to $[AB'']$ on $z$ axis. You can then perform the required rotation $Z(-\theta)$ about $[AB'']$ and then rotate back to undo the first two rotations. The required transformation is then:
$$
Z(-\alpha)X(-\beta)Z(-\theta)X(\beta)Z(\alpha).
$$

Comment: Could you be more specific in the computation of the angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ? Maybe describing how you obtained them.

Comment: It's only some simple trigonometry.

Comment: Nevermind, I saw it, it is simple :D

Comment: The distance of $B$ from $z$ axis is $\sqrt5/2$, so...

Comment: Well, I did like this : first, I projected $B$ onto the $yz$-plane and obtained a point $C(0,1,0.5)$. Therefore, the angle $\sphericalangle (C,Oz) = \arctan (\frac{1-0}{0.5-0})$

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it.